# JQuery dropdown menu three levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menu with three levels:

HTML:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul class="level2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">item1</a>
                <ul class="level3">
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.main-menu li a {
    color: #000;
}
.level3,
.level2 {
    display: none;
}
.main-menu li.active .level2 {
    display: block;
}

.level2 li.active .level3 {
    display: block;
}
```

Script:

```
$('.main-menu > li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('.level2 > li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

The problem is that when I click on an element of the second level, then the list of the third does not open. How to fix it? And how to refactor the code not to be repeated?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r14nep26/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) tp prevent bubling of events from child to parent elements.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r14nep26/3/)**

```
$('.main-menu > li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.level2 > li').removeClass('active');
});

$('.level2 > li').click(function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: When I click on the items in the main menu, then all of them added class active! How fix?